# How to add case in my query in SQL Server 2008 and 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to add case please help vehicle = 'Stop' addvalues start from starting, and it movingstatus = 'carmoving' values add contentiously in addvalues column

```
insert into TackHistory values(GETDATE(),GETDATE(),'Moving')


WITH rows AS 
(
    SELECT  
        *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY gps_time) AS rn
    FROM    
        TackHistory
    WHERE
        car_id = 12956 
),
differences AS  
(
    SELECT  
        mc.rn, mc.gps_time, DATEDIFF(second, mc.gps_time, mp.gps_time) time_diff
    FROM    
        rows mc
    JOIN
        rows mp ON mc.rn = mp.rn - 1
)
SELECT 
    t1.gps_time, t1.time_diff, SUM(t2.time_diff) time_sum
FROM 
    differences t1
INNER JOIN 
    differences t2 ON t1.rn >= t2.rn
GROUP BY 
    t1.rn, t1.gps_time, t1.time_diff
ORDER BY 
    t1.rn
```

SQL Server 2012 query

```
SELECT 
    gps_time,
    DATEDIFF(second, LAG(gps_time) OVER (ORDER BY gps_time), gps_time) time_diff,
    DATEDIFF(second, MIN(gps_time) OVER (ORDER BY gps_time), gps_time) time_sum
FROM
    TackHistory
ORDER BY 
    gps_time
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: how to add case this situation